# Trouble compiling Enlightenment foundation library 1.8.5

Tags: linux, debian, pkg-config, efl

When I run configure.sh 
I get this error:
checking for pkg-config... no
configure: error: pkg-config tool not found. Install it or set PKG_CONFIG environment variable to that path tool. Exiting...
I checked in aptitude and it says pkg-config is installed.
Need help with
 "set PKG_CONFIG environment variable to that path tool."
runing on crunchbang 32bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set PKG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pkg-config although it should be detected in such PATH automatically unless you've changed your PATH variable before.

You may also check if it is possible to pass path to pkg-config as a configure switch.

Check the output of `./configure --help | grep pkg`.